# Versioning with url in ASP.NET Core - problem with multiple matching endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, versioning

I am making v2 of my API. In v1 I had version in URL, so it was api/v1/something. Now I'm adding second version of API and decided to use Asp.Versioning.Mvc. So currently my controller looks like this:

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    public class SomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        //ctor

        [HttpGet]
        [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SomeResponse?>> GetSomethingV1([FromQuery] string text)
        {
            ...
        {

        [HttpGet]
        [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<SomeResponse?>> GetSomethingV2([FromQuery] string text)
        {
            ...
        {
    }
```

And also in Startup.cs

```
services.AddApiVersioning(config =>
            {
                config.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(2.0);
                config.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                config.ReportApiVersions = true;
            });
services.AddMvc();
```

Unfortunately it keeps giving me exception Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Any idea why could that be?

I tried several combinations of attributes to test if maybe I understand something wrong but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Provide details. What request throws that exception?

Comment: Well since there are only Get controllers let's say it was GET on api/v1.0/Some?text=test. Same could be for api/v2.0/Some?text=test

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you split the version `1.0` and `2.0` into their individual controllers. Having two different version in same controller is what's confusing ASP.NET.

Like this

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    //ctor

    [HttpGet]
    [MapToApiVersion("1.0")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SomeResponse?>> GetSomethingV1([FromQuery] string text)
    {

    }

}
```

And

```
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ApiVersion("2.0")]
public class SomeController : ControllerBase
{
    //ctor

    [HttpGet]
    [MapToApiVersion("2.0")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<SomeResponse?>> GetSomethingV2([FromQuery] string text)
    {

    }
}
```

This way you can organize versions their respective controllers. You can utilize inheritance as well if you don't want to create two version for a single domain. But that gets tricky as mentioned here : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/801#issuecomment-1025948364

Comment: So It is not possible to have them in same controller? I thought it was but couldn't find anything about it in the docs

Comment: I don't think it is possible